# Cannot create root jail

Tags: linux, bash, chroot

I just tried to play around with chroot command only for testing purposes, in order to create a temporary root jail, but I didn't managed to. The platform is CentOS 6.4. and I have done it numerous times so far except for now. I followed the procedure in that order:

1. Create `bin`, `etc`, `home`, `lib`, and `var` directories.
2. `ldd /bin/bash`
3. Copy all libraries in above mentioned `lib` directory plus `/bin/bash` binary in `bin`.
4. Then ran `chroot /path/to/the/jail` and the following appeared:

   ```
   chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
   ```

I am not able to establish where this error comes from and also I have never had such a problem. The same procedure works just fine in Ubuntu server. The problem occurs only on this particular server.

Per comments below, here is some output from debugging commands:

```
[root@localhost chroot]# find -printf '%M %p\n'
 drwxr-xr-x .
 drwxr-xr-x ./bin
 -rwxr-xr-x ./bin/bash
 drwxr-xr-x ./var
 drwxr-xr-x ./var/var
 drwxr-xr-x ./home
 drwxr-xr-x ./lib
 -rwxr-xr-x ./lib/libdl.so.2
 -rwxr-xr-x ./lib/libc.so.6
 -rwxr-xr-x ./lib/libtinfo.so.5
 -rwxr-xr-x ./lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 drwxr-xr-x ./etc
```

```
[root@localhost bin]# ldd /mnt/proba1/chroot/bin/bash
 linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff6fe00000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f12cdd40000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f12cdb38000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12cd7a0000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12cdf70000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ldd` output shows that `bash` is expecting to find its libraries in `/lib64`, not `/lib`. Also, this means you have to copy them *from* `/lib64` into the corresponding directory inside the jail. The same files found in `/lib` won't work.

Comment: Yes, I spotted it and I did so, just forgot to mention it, I basically copied the ldd output with just one "cp" before the line, so it's being done.

Comment: @DreadX: So edit your question to show the actual state of things. Don't make people chase details all over the page.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I use "mount --bind" for this. You can also make it read-only.
eg:

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir bin sbin usr etc
mount --bind -o ro /bin bin
mount --bind -o ro /sbin sbin
mount --bind -o ro /usr usr
mount --bind -o ro /etc etc
chroot .
```

This isn't completely, but you get the idea.
This can get really cool if you use "aufs" as well. It allows you to layer a writable layer on top of a readable layer. That way, you don't end up having to copy, bind-mount it read-only, yet still make it writable, while all the writes are kept in a placeholder somewhere.
Another thing to try is using 'cp -l' link-copying. And then "cow" which means copy-on-write. What that does is it first makes a copy, but all the directory entries pointing to the same nodes on disk. It looks like a copy, but they're all linked. Not symbolically linked, but hard linked.
Cow makes it so that the moment you try to write to the file, that file's actual content first gets copied, and that then gets modified.